# Use of ajaxSuccess in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

i'm having a hard time to find a solution to use jquery ajaxSuccess in a chrome extension

it's simple :
here is the content.js :

```
$('#message').ajaxSuccess(function (){
    alert('b');
});
```

and ... :

"permissions":
    [
        "unlimited_storage",
        "notifications",
        "http://*/"
    ]

Comment: How are you making your actual Ajax calls? If `ajaxSuccess` event listener is not firing, it suggests that no Ajax call is successfully completing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are making valid Ajax calls that should trigger the `ajaxSuccess` event, the most likely issue is that `http://*/` is not a valid host-permission [match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html), causing your cross-domain Ajax requests to fail.  The correct form to match all HTTP pages would be `http://*/*` (not ethe final `*`), and the correct form to match all pages over both HTTP and HTTPS is `*://*/*`.